# Get routeParams value into a controller in Angular

Tags: angularjs, routes

I am having trouble getting routeParams into an Angular controller.

```
app.controller("ReplicatedCtrl", function(ReplicatedService, $routeParams) {
  var replicated = this;

  replicated.myPhone = $routeParams.myPhone;
  console.log(replicated.myPhone); // logs undefined
```

My $roteProvider:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/:myPhone', {
        templateUrl: function(attrs){
            console.log(attrs.myPhone);
            return 'pages/8week/8week-page.tmpl.html';
        },
        controller: 'EightWeekCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'eight'
    });
```

The primary controller is different from the the controller I'm trying pass this value to. I was under the impression that $routeParams functions much like $scope. Is it just isolated to the controller assigned to the route?

Comment: That means that the route using that controller doesn't have such a param, or that the controller is used in a route that doesn't have such a param. Without your code, it's impossible to say more.

Comment: could you add your router configuration.. as like @JBNizet said you might not added a parameter in route itself..

Comment: Are $routeParam attributes not available outside of a specific controller?

Comment: did you include it in your config ?

Comment: No? Is that what I need to do?

Comment: I do have `$routeProvider` in my config

Comment: Where, and how, is ReplicatedCtrl used?

Answer (score -1):

I think what your looking for is $state value which returns an object and see what you need from there. Make sure you include it in you controller like below. Let me know if this is it, or I can update.

```
function ExampleCtrl($state) {
  'use strict';

  var ctrl = this;

  console.log($state);
}

// Should output something like this.
Object {
  params: Object,
  current: Object,
  $current: extend,
  transition: null
}
$current
  :
  extend
current
  :
  Object
get: (stateOrName, context)
go: go(to, params, options)
href: href(stateOrName, params, options)
includes: includes(stateOrName, params, options)
is: is(stateOrName, params, options)
params: Object
reload: reload(state)
transition: null
transitionTo: transitionTo(to, toParams, options)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Curious about the down vote? I did say I would update, from what OP gave us its seems like he was looking for $state and it object values.